# I can't connect to SQL Server database from Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I need to connect to a SQL server database from Python. In this case, I am a non-administrator Windows user.

This is the code that I used:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=XXXXXXXX;'
                      'Database=XXX;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      'port = 1433;')
```

But this error message appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-c018c40360dc>", line 3, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'

ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "XXX" requested by login. Login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000 ] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0);[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "XXX" requested by login . Login failed. (4060); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

This is the Conection Section in my SQL Server Manangement Studio:

[image]

The image description:

- Server Type: Database Engine

  Server Name: XXXXX

  Authentication: Windows Authentication

  Username: SERVERNAME / username

  Password: (empty)

What am i making wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use different Driver? see pyodbc documentation  section Databases https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/ConnectionStrings.wiki#Security

Comment: Instead of `port = 1433;` have you tried `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` and `SERVER=XXXXXXXX,1433;`? REF: [Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc#connect)

Comment: *"Cannot open database "XXX" requested by login"* - When you connect via SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) are you able to open the database you specified as `DATABASE=` in the connection string? Could there be a typo in the database name? Are you running the Python script under the same account that you use to run SSMS?

Comment: To echo @Gord, the error message your seeing is coming from the db server and trying you that you don't have permission in the database your trying to connect to. Take a look in the server's error log to corroborate the details.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, i have tried " 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'Server=XXX, 1433;'
                      'Database=XXX;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'  " and haven't worked too...

Comment: @GordThompson, yes, i can connect it via SSMS, because in the "Server Conection" window appear in username the name of the non-administrator Windows user. No, there is no typo in database name. Maybe the error is that i'm running script under a different account, but i don't know how to make it correctly.

Comment: How does your script get launched? Do you open a command prompt (CMD or PowerShell) and type `python my_script.py` ?

Comment: I can see the problem! It was my username really didn't have acess to the database and I need to Grant it! Thanks, @GordThompson, your tip help me!